# ActiveAdmin - set dynamic title panel/sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I haven't been able to find a clear answer in the ActiveAdmin docs, or elsewhere. Is there a way to dynamically set the title of a panel or sidebar? For example, I need to have the name of the resource that I'm filtered to included in the title. Is that possible?

Comment: Never used activeAdmin, but overall you could create a helper method

Answer (score 0):

```
panel "#{resource.name}", class: "panel_with_resource_name" do
 .....
end
```

or maybe you are looking for this?

```
controller do
    before_action {  
      @title = " #{Model.find(params[:your_object_id]).try(:whatever_params)}"
    }
  end
```

or

```
controller do
    def whatever_action
      @title = "this is"+resource.name
    end
  end
```

then in view

```
whatever_action:title=> @title  do
 .....
end
```